# Llamar variable de MainActivity a una clase de servicio en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, variables, servicio

Tengo una aplicación que obtiene la ubicación del usuario, ahora necesito enviar esos valores (latitud, longitud) al momento de lanzar un servicio..

```
//Variables donde se guardan las coordenadas
Double lati = new Double(0);
Double longi = new Double(0);

//Variables para convertir a String las coordenadas
public String latis = Double.toString(lati);
public String longis = Double.toString(longi);    

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Método para obtener la ubicación
    locationStart();

    // Se lanza el servicio
    startService(new Intent(this, ServiceDemo.class));
}
```

Como puedo pasar esas variables?

Intenté obtener la ubicación desde la clase Servicio, pero me marcaba error al momento de castear al MainActivity. Por lo cual opté por pasar directamente las variables, pero aún no encuentro ninguna solución.

Comment: Hola Agus. Has probado a pasarle los parámetros en el intent y recogerlos despues en el servicio con getIntent().getBundles()?

Answer (score 1):

Como dice Pablo lo mejor que puedes hacer es pasar datos en el intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServiceDemo.class);
intent.putExtra("latis", latis);
intent.putExtra("longis", longis);
startActivity(intent);
```

Y en tu clase Service Demo...

```
String latis_service = getIntent().getStringExtra("latis");
String longis_service = getIntent().getStringExtra("longis");
```

Answer (score 0):

Le enviarías un Intent que está dirigido a tu clase precisa. Algo así en la Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Servicio.class);
intent.putExtra("nameVar",data);
startService(intent);
```

y en el servicio de esta manera:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String stringVar = intent.getStringExtra("nameVar");
    System.out.println(stringVar);
return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: @Agus olivera Asi tendria que funcionar